# How to use tensorflow.data.Dataset.flat_map(my_func) with a function of multiple paramters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have this code as part of windowing function:

```
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
    dataset = dataset.window(size=window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size))
```

However, in the TF Certification exam I can't use **lambda**! so, I need to get rid of the **lambda** part. I tried using a function like so:

```
def window_to_tensor(window_ds: tf.data.Dataset, window_size: int):
    return window_ds.batch(window_size)

dataset = dataset.flat_map(window_to_tensor ,window_size)
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: flat_map() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Even when I try to use two functions like below, I get a similar error:

```
dataset = dataset.apply(window_to_tensor,window_size)
dataset = tf.keras.backend.flatten(dataset)
```

How can I map a function then flatten the resulting dataset without using flat_map (or with using it but without lambda)? (I am required to use TF2.0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use lambda. Only lambda *layers* are forbidden:

[image]

You can read the [instructions](https://utility.trueability.com/google/tensor-flow/Instructions_for_taking_the_TensorFlow_Certificate_exam.pdf) yourself.

So you can do the windowed dataset like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

window_size = 5

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.rand(100))
dataset = dataset.window(window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(5))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1:])).batch(4)

next(iter(dataset))
```

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=float64, numpy=
 array([[0.82421497, 0.02775336, 0.51822687, 0.99682813],
        [0.02775336, 0.51822687, 0.99682813, 0.25681553],
        [0.51822687, 0.99682813, 0.25681553, 0.80613281],
        [0.99682813, 0.25681553, 0.80613281, 0.01170842]])>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 1), dtype=float64, numpy=
 array([[0.25681553],
        [0.80613281],
        [0.01170842],
        [0.01685387]])>)
```

Comment: I guess I need to have some sleep to refresh my focus! Thank you for the correction